# Boilerplate Code for a DirectX 11 + ImGui Hook

Tags: c++, hook, overlay, directx-11, imgui

I'm trying to understand how a DirectX 11 + ImGui hook works.

I've seen a lot of repos, but all of them seem to be bloated with extra code and are difficult to understand which parts of code are the necessary ones, and what each one do, why they are there.

What would be the absolutely most minimal code to make an ImGui overlay appear on a (DX11) game?

What each code-part/line does, and why it's needed?

Thank you.

Comment: imgui pretends to be bloat-free. The dx11 (+win32) backend is ~2000 lines of code and dx11 sample is 250 lines of code. It's going to be difficult to be much more simple than this, you do need to have some platform-specific code.

Comment: @SimonMourier I'll ask it differently: What do i need to know, in order to make a DirectX 11 + ImGui hook? (Beyond ImGui knowledge) how to set up a project and its codebase, in order to have a working DLL that can be injected into a video game? I'm not asking to find an already made solution, but how to make one from scratch. I'm not saying to write DirectX or ImGui from scratch... but how to combine the needed technologies, and to understand the reasoning behind the usage/combination of each one of them. How to combine them, and what these lines of code do and why they're needed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: "Hooking into a video game" is a complex project for many reasons, so I don't think it's fair to say the problem is DirectX or ImGui.